# Using NodeJS to run an Angular 2 app while having live repackaging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack

**Description**

I used to have `NodeJS` run on `:3000` and my `ng serve'd` `Angular2` app run on `:4200` where they would communicate. I am using `WebPack`

I now build using `ng build -prod` for the `Angular2` app and have the `NodeJS` app read the staging (dist) folder and serve the static files itself.

**Problem**

When I split the responsibilities I used to be able to have the page refresh automatically `ng serve` would work with `angular-cli` and magic would happen.

But now that I'm having `NodeJS` serve the static files, i'm forced to `ng build -prod` each time I want to refresh the page.

Anyone know how I can have it repackage to the staging folder?

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using `ng eject` which will split the `webpack.config.js` from the CLI. Then you can boot up an Express server or something and use a module like Webpack hot middleware.

Be warned, this will break some of the Angular CLI functionality (`ng serve`, for example won't work, but `npm start` will). So, you might consider creating a branch before starting.

Answer (score 0):

alright, I found something that works for now. automatic refresh does not work but I don't mind manually refreshing the page again

I move into my `Portal` directory the directory currently running the `:4200` app and run `ng build --watch`. This allows me to still start my server through `npm start` but now rebuilds (quickly) and updates the bundles when I save a file.